# MATLAB binary systems

Tags: matlab, binary

`(10000000)2 = -128 %` there are 8 digits
`2^7-1=127=(01111111)2` & there are 8 digits

My MATLAB instructor says that these are true, but I don't know how this works.

I understand 127, but I don't understand about -128. She says something like the first digit in -128, which is 1, is used for determining a sign. But if that is the cases, in `(10000000)2`, there is no digit that makes it `2^7`. Can anyone explain?

Comment: Wouldn't this be a good question to ask your instructor?

Comment: can't reach her for a while from now

Comment: Try reading up on [signed number representations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signed_number_representations). In general i do not think that this is a matlab question.

Comment: That representation is known as [Two's Complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two's_complement).  It is not specific to MATLAB.  It is a number representation valid on any digital computer. I've marked an appropriate duplicate for you to read.